# Excel formula for earliest date ONLY when value a second column matches the value a third column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

SOLVED - No further efforts required. Formula below.

I am trying to create a function that works across two worksheets to find the earliest date if it matches criteria in 2010. The goal is to continuously see the most out-of-date item that has the same "name", so that it can be reviewed and made current. The process repeats.

The first worksheet produces a summary for a product. The second is a collection of metadata for the product. I would like to find a function that compares a column to a single cell on the first worksheet and produces the earliest date from the rows on the second worksheet that match.
Here's the basic idea:

[IMGUR LINK TO SCREENSHOT OF CONCEPT. Sorry. Doesn't seem to let me embed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWoFp.png)

It is important that if a 4th AA is added, the formula finds it and continues to account for it.

I've tried some combinations of IF, VLOOKUP, and MINA or MIN, but can't seem to get it to work.

The closest I've gotten is

=MIN(IF(A11:A18=A3, C11:C18, broken).

But that doesn't seem to work when I raise the amount of values in the arrays.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

SOLVED: Function was correct. I forgot to use "ctrl+shift+enter". Keeping post active for others to reference.

Answer (score 0):

Try
`=MIN(IF(A3=Sheet2!A:A,Sheet2!B:B))` entered as an array formula (Ctrl+Shift+Enter)...This formula assumes that your text criteria is in Column A of Sheet 2 and your date criteria is in Column B of Sheet two.  This formula would be pasted in cell B3.

Comment: Thanks, Mongoose. Unfortunately my reputation is too low to change your answer score.